# How to customize uitableview selected item background

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to make a special selection of the selected item
[image: basic selected]

I wish it looked as:
[image: I wish it looked as]

how can I make Uitableview Selected item looked exactly like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(itemlst,curValue);
NSIndexPath path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(index, 0);
 var cell = LanguageList.CellAt(path); // language list it`s UiTableView
                var selectedItemView = new UIView ();
                var image = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromFile ("active.png"));
                image.Frame = new RectangleF (300, 17, 10, 10);
                selectedItemView.AddSubview (image);
                selectedItemView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
                selectedItemView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB (50,50, 50).CGColor;
                cell.SelectedBackgroundView = selectedItemView;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a build-in *accessory* in the selected cell, you should add something like the following code to the **RowSelected()** method override in your *UITableViewSource* class:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // do something with your data...
    // data is a model object that contain a public bool Selected {get; set;} property
    // myDataCollection is a collection of model objects

    var data = myDataCollection [indexPath.Row];
    var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);

    if (data.Selected)
    {
        data.Selected = false;
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    }
    else
    {
        data.Selected = true;
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
    }

    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
}        
}
```

Available members for the *UITableViewCellAccessory* enum are: *Checkmark*, *DetailButton*, *DetailDisclosureButton*, *DisclosureIndicator* and *None*.

Note that you should keep track of the cell that has been selected in your model class and set you accessory also in the **GetCell()** method to prevent the accessory being displayed on cells that have been recycled by the *DequeueReusableCell()* method when they scroll outside the screen.

If you want to display an arbitrary UIImage of your choice you need to replace the code above with:

```
cell.AccessoryView = myImageView;
```

where *myImageView* is an *UIImageView* with your image loaded from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can set SelectedBackgroundView property

```
cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new MyView()
```

Comment: It seems from the picture above the OP wants to add an accessory view to the cell, not a background (even if the title states otherwise).